# How to tie mariaDB into modular javafx application

Tags: javafx, module, mariadb

In my quest to upgrade a legacy javafx application to a modular java 17 installable package, I have arrived at a new impasse: I don't know how to add the mariadb module information to my module-info.java file.
While debuging the jar, I got the following error message:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mariadb://192.168.2.24:3306/ChainPro
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:706)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:190)
    at com.papaworx.chainpro_m.utilities.GConnection.<init>(GConnection.java:105)
    at com.papaworx.chainpro_m.Main.start(Main.java:83)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:847)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:484)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:457)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$11(GtkApplication.java:316)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

I have installed the newest mariadb jdbc, but how do I tell the module info?

Comment: Don't you just need `requires something;` in the `module-info` file?